# Vector holding a class which holds a pointers

Tags: c++, pointers

I have a template class Position which has a pointer to an Entry object. Can it creates errors if I am creating my Positions on the stack, and then inserting them in the std::vector?

Here is my Position Template:

```
template <typename K, typename V>
class Position
{
private:
    Entry<K, V> *ptr;
    int index;
public:
    Position(Entry<K,V> &e, int index){
        *ptr = e;
        this->index = index;
    }
```

And I am inserting like this in the vector:

```
Entry<int, int> e(20, 20);
//Creates Position with reference to Entry and Index as value.
storage.push_back(Position<K,V> p(e, 10));
```

I am not fully sure how would memory work for a simple insertion. Even more if I am inserting inside a local function, and the Position is created locally.

So, can I do it, should I use new so it stays on the Heap? Am I doing things wrong?
Thanks for the help in advance.

Comment: Please read [ask] with a [mcve].  There is too much code missing from the question to do any thing other than guess at an answer. A `std::vector` holds a copy of what you put into it, So it all depends on how `Position::ptr` is used.  Is it an owning pointer or not? If it is an owning pointer you should read [The rule of three/five/zero](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/rule_of_three) and/or try not to use a pointer.

Comment: C++ is a lot more pleasant without pointers. Are you *sure* you need a pointer here?

Comment: It's not clear what's right or wrong here, as this code might be a bit too trivial. A) What does the pointer do? B) Where does it get initialized? C) You could `emplace_back`.

Comment: I need a way to keep my Entries as reference, and yes the position does hold an Entry. Since vector copy elements and does not keep references, I thought I could just implement a class which holds a pointer.

Comment: Does this class own the Entry (manage it's lifetime) or just point-to/observe it?  You have deleted the code you are asking about and we need to see more of it.

Comment: I'm sorry, here I have added the constructor to the class. The position takes an Entry as reference and points to it. Then, it is inserted inside the Vector. Is this a good way to do things or I should not.

Comment: You can make a class that does nothing but hold a pointer and often this is a great idea, but since the `vector`'s going to copy and move instances of that class around as objects are inserted and the `vector` is resized, that class has to make sure that the pointed-at objects are copied and moved and potentially destroyed correctly. See the [Rule of Three](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/rule_of_three) for details. For us out here to make sense of the question we absolutely must see the class's destructor, copy and move constructors and copy and move assignment operators.

Comment: `*ptr = e;`: You are dereferencing an uninitialized pointer. You can't do that. You need to make `ptr` point to something before you use `*ptr`.

Comment: There are many operations on `std::vector` that can **invalidate pointers**, so be sure you know what those are and have accounted for that here.

Comment: Maybe what this needs is a reference to the vector and an index, *at most*. With that information it can get a reference to the vector's element at that index.

Comment: Ok thanks. I am going to work on move constuctor, and rule of threes. All new stuff for me, I have tried implementing the data structures I have learned in Java into C++, and it seems like I am missing out important knowledge about the language.

Comment: *"I'm sorry, here I have added the constructor to the class. The position takes an Entry as reference and points to it. Then, it is inserted inside the Vector"* - that's not at all what you're doing here. You have an uninitialized pointer that points to random memory, and you assign *through* that pointer, overwriting some memory you don't own. If you want to point to something, you use would `ptr = &e`. If you want to assign *through* the pointer, you would do what you're doing: `*ptr = e`...

Comment: In the former case, you need to allocate memory for `ptr` to point to, before you copy `e` into that destination. In the later case, you need to make sure `e` is not deallocated while `ptr` still holds its address. If you fix your code to use `ptr = &e`, you will certainly be taking the address of a variable that will go away while you still have its address in `ptr`, again causing you to incorrectly point to memory you don't own.

Comment: I did C into Java and wrote rather bad Java code for a few years before investing in some good books on Java. In hindsight, I never really got that good at Java. A few years later, I made the exact same mistake thinking, "I know C and I know Java, so C++ is gonna be a breeze!" Over a decade later I'm still finding and silently fixing the C++ code I wrote  for those first few years. Frankly, I'm not sure I'm that good at C++ either. I'm just a LOT more careful. I recommend Scott Meyers' Effective C++ books to help you brush up.

Comment: @user4581301 Thank you, I'll be reading that. Seems like your right, I have got to change how I see things, or I won't be able to do it.

Comment: @MaximeLandry -- `Entry<K, V> *ptr;` -- This looks a lot like you are trying to take Java examples and retrofitting it to C++.  What you are trying to do is taken care of by `std::vector<std::pair<T1, T2>>` or `std::map<K, V>`.  The bottom line is you should not use Java or any other language as a model in writing C++ code.  All that will happen if you do this is 1) You will have programs that are inefficient, 2) You will have programs that are buggy, or 3) You will have programs that will look weird to a C++ programmer.

Answer (score 1):

I am going to address you question at a few different levels: 1) cleanup the code you posted because it is not doing what you think it is, 2) address your intuition about storing a pointer to an object that goes out of scope, and 3) walk through some alternate design options that don't use pointers.

### Posted Code

Consider the `Position` constructor. The first argument is a reference to an `Entry`. The expression `*ptr = e` copies the object referenced by `e` and stores it in the location pointed to by `ptr` which is uninitialized and could point anywhere, clearly a bug. Based on your verbal explanation, I think the expression should have been `ptr = &e`, which stores the address of `e` in `ptr`.

### Storing Pointers

You intuition is correct that storing a pointer to an object that goes out of scope will certainly fail. As you mention, one option is to allocate the object on the heap and store that pointer which will remain valid until you delete the object from the heap. That said, I recommend not working with raw with pointers.

### Design Options

I don't know your overall code, so you may have to adapt these strategies to your situation.

1. Store the `Entry` object directly in the `Position`. This is clearly the easiest solution assuming it still meets the other requirements of your code, i.e. the `Entry`'s are not somehow shared or changed outside of the `Position` object.
2. Allocate the `Entry` object using `new` but store the result in a smart pointer like `std::unique_ptr` (or `stud::shared_ptr` if you need multiple references to it). The smart pointer can be passed around and stored in objects by value similar to an `int`. I can't overstate how much better this is than working with raw pointers.

### Asking Questions

When you post a question, it is really helpful to post enough code to replicate the problem you are experiencing. The code should compile (unless the question is about a compilation error) and run.

This had multiple benefits. For the questioner, often to process of constructing a minimal, reproducible example points them in the right direction. It also turns the question into a reliable specification of the issue. For the answerers, it makes it a lot easier to work on the problem.

Comment: Thank you very much for this answer. I will try to adjust my code accordingly.